# Being able to access a property with and without class instantiation?

Tags: php, oop, properties

I have a class which has a certain property that i need access to both without and with class instantiation.
I felt smart and declared it as public static after reading the internet and voila, i was able to access the value using :: without actually creating an object of that class.

Now, some hours down the road i need to access the same value, but this time over the course of looping over an array that holds an actual instance of the class and i cant access it....

Please advise

```
Class Omega{
   public static $value = 500;
}

$name = "Omega";
$prop = "value";
$cost = $name::$$prop // 500 yay it works


$omega = new Omega();
$ships[] = $omega;

$totalCost = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($ships); $i++){
   $totalCost = $totalCost + $ships[i$]->value; // UGH    
}
```

I am getting the following notices:

> Notice: Accessing static property Omega::$value as non static in C:\xampp\htdocs\fire\test.php on line 44

and

> Notice: Undefined property: Omega::$value in C:\xampp\htdocs\fire\test.php on line 44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is still part of the class since it's a static property. You can access it with `$ships[$i]::$value`.

Comment: You sure ? Because its not working for me.

http://prntscr.com/d1sx71
top error, left class, right code being called.

Comment: I'm sure. `+` isn't the concatenation operator of php. it's `.` instead. Also, remove the `;` after them.

Comment: Goddamn. Im sorry for bothering you. Thanks.

Comment: As a note, i fixed my errors but i could only access the prop with
$ships[$i]::$value instead of $ships[$i]::value !

Answer (score 1):

This is not the properly use of static property, because only one instance of then exist, so every `$ships[$i]::$value` has exactly same value.

Errors in code: `Class Omega(){` => `class Omega {`, `$ships[i$]->value` => `$ships[$i]::$value`

Consider this:

```
class Omega {
   public static $value = 500;
}

$arr = [new Omega(), new Omega()];
echo $arr[0]::$value . "\n";
echo $arr[1]::$value . "\n";

$arr[0]::$value = 400;

echo $arr[0]::$value . "\n";
echo $arr[1]::$value . "\n";
```

Output:

```
500
500
400
400
```

Comment: Thats funny. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Note, what you want to do, is done by construct and __toString method. Static methods are called without being instantiated outside the class.

If you want your task done , try __toString() mehtod to have this